# ERROR: ld.so: object 'libtcmalloc.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignore

Tags: python, gradio

ERROR: ld.so: object 'libtcmalloc.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

ERROR: ld.so: object 'libtcmalloc.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

ERROR: ld.so: object 'libtcmalloc.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

ERROR: ld.so: object 'libtcmalloc.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/sd/stable-diffusion-webui/webui.py", line 22, in

```
import gradio
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/gradio/**init**.py", line 3, in

```
import gradio.components as components
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/gradio/components/**init**.py", line 1, in

```
from gradio.components.annotated_image import AnnotatedImage
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/gradio/components/annotated_image.py", line 13, in

```
from gradio.components.base import IOComponent, _Keywords
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/gradio/components/base.py", line 29, in

```
from gradio.blocks import Block, BlockContext
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/gradio/blocks.py", line 1382

```
self.server_name = "d.so: object 'libtcmalloc.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

                   ^
```

SyntaxError: unterminated string literal (detected at line 1382)

I need to solve above problem